# Want to order on two columns but not the usual way

Tags: mysql, order-by

I have a table as below

```
ID  userID  Date
1   2273    22/08/2011
2   2274    24/08/2011
3   2275    26/08/2011
4   2273    26/08/2011
5   2273    26/08/2011
6   2271    26/08/2011
```

And want result as below.  Need mysql query help to acheive this. Basically i want to order by date but same user must all be together. And i am trying to achieve this in single query.

```
ID  userID  Date
1   2273    22/08/2011
4   2273    26/08/2011
5   2273    26/08/2011
2   2274    24/08/2011
3   2275    26/08/2011
6   2271    26/08/2011
```

I tries select * from mytable order by userId,Date and will result in following

```
ID  userID  Date
6   2271    26/08/2011
1   2273    22/08/2011
4   2273    26/08/2011
5   2273    26/08/2011
2   2274    24/08/2011
3   2275    26/08/2011
```

Which is not i want i want user with date ascending should come first and same user records in table should follow his first record...

Comment: How's the usual way?

Comment: Your sample output is achieved by ORDER BY userID, Date. Fix your question and try again. -1 and vote to close.

Comment: @Marian SELECT * FROM Mytable ORDER BY userID, Date

Comment: @gbn i edited question..

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: @gbn: we all misread the output thinking it's a simple Order By issue :-). I was going to vote on close too, when I read again the desired output, which was not exactly what we thought. I guess we can remove the down votes.

Comment: @Marian : yep, done

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT *
FROM Mytable
ORDER BY
   userID, Date
```

I assume Date is really a date/time type and not varchar...

Edit, after clarification:

Untested

```
SELECT
    M.*
FROM
    ( --one row for each user
    SELECT MIN(Date) AS FirstUserDate, userID
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY userID
    ) foo
    JOIN
    MyTable M ON foo.userID = M.userID
ORDER BY
    foo.FirstUserDate, M.userID, M.Date;
```

Answer (score 5):

I think this query will do it for you

```
SELECT A.*
FROM userorder A LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM userorder
WHERE userID=
(SELECT MIN(userID) FROM userorder
WHERE Date=(SELECT MAX(Date)
FROM userorder ORDER BY userID))) B
USING (ID)
ORDER BY IFNULL(B.ID,-1),userId,Date;
```

I actually used your sample data and tried it in MySQL 5.5.12 on my PC

```
mysql> use test
Database changed
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS userorder;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE userorder (ID int,userID int,Date date);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.16 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO userorder VALUES
    -> (1,2273,'2011-08-22'),
    -> (2,2274,'2011-08-24'),
    -> (3,2275,'2011-08-26'),
    -> (4,2273,'2011-08-26'),
    -> (5,2273,'2011-08-26'),
    -> (6,2271,'2011-08-26');
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM userorder;
+------+--------+------------+
| ID   | userID | Date       |
+------+--------+------------+
|    1 |   2273 | 2011-08-22 |
|    2 |   2274 | 2011-08-24 |
|    3 |   2275 | 2011-08-26 |
|    4 |   2273 | 2011-08-26 |
|    5 |   2273 | 2011-08-26 |
|    6 |   2271 | 2011-08-26 |
+------+--------+------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT A.*
    -> FROM userorder A LEFT JOIN
    -> (SELECT * FROM userorder
    -> WHERE userID=
    -> (SELECT MIN(userID) FROM userorder
    -> WHERE Date=(SELECT MAX(Date)
    -> FROM userorder ORDER BY userID))) B
    -> USING (ID)
    -> ORDER BY IFNULL(B.ID,-1),userId,Date;
+------+--------+------------+
| ID   | userID | Date       |
+------+--------+------------+
|    1 |   2273 | 2011-08-22 |
|    4 |   2273 | 2011-08-26 |
|    5 |   2273 | 2011-08-26 |
|    2 |   2274 | 2011-08-24 |
|    3 |   2275 | 2011-08-26 |
|    6 |   2271 | 2011-08-26 |
+------+--------+------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Wonder what the performance impact of using that IFNULL() in the order by clause is, on a table with millions of rows. Of course the entire thing looks complex, but the IFNULL is just what jumps out at me!

Comment: @DTest - IMHO This query fits this data set to a tee. I have no clue what performance impact could possibly be. I am sure it has O(n^2) written all over it. However, there was a great performance impact just thinking about this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you're looking for?  It's just a sort by userID and Date.

```
select ID, userID, Date
from Table
order by userID, Date
```

Comment: Not at all, i tried what it will do is first sort by user id and than within that it will sort by date. means users with ids smaller will always be first no matter what date is...